# How do I record sound on a Thinkpad Edge 11?

Tags: 10.10, sound

I Cannot record sound - so neither empathy nor any SIP software works.

I am updateing it regularly. I am 100% sure that this is a driver problem - I installed Fedora and had same problem with sound. I read about forcing the `snd-hda-intel` driver - but did not find anything about the ThinkPad Edge 11.

Link to reported bug:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/alsa-driver/+bug/683926

Comment: Can you please provide some more information about your system?

Comment: This symptom is highly reminiscent of a defect report.  Please use `ubuntu-bug alsa-base`, and, as Jorge says above, edit your question with a link to the bug report.  We (the audio developers) will triage your defect report and continue here as appropriate.

Comment: Is now the report OK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After few tests I found it!

I've added to `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf`

```
options snd-hda-intel model="ideapad"
```

And voila! I can make records with internal mic!

Tested with pavucontrol, Sound Recorder and skype.

Answer (score 0):

cat /etc/*release*
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=10.10
DISTRIB_CODENAME=maverick
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 10.10"

I that enough?
I am updateing it regularry.

I am 10001% sure that this is a driver problem - I installed Fedora and had same problem with sound.
I red about fircing te snd-hda-intel driver - but did not found something about ThinkPad Edge 11.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu, I've updated your original question with this information. Please read the information here: http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/257/how-does-ask-ubuntu-work and then just delete this answer and just update your question with the information as you debug your problem.

Comment: I found two reported bugs:

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/682565
and 
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/587388
will try the second one